# Why does Google Search's unit converter return incorrect values for femtometers?

Tags: google-search, google-calculator

A femtometer (fm) is a unit of length equal to one quadrillionth of a meter:

```
1 fm = 10-15 m = 1e-15 m
```

When I use Google Search's built-in unit conversion to calculate 3 femtometers, instead of returning the expected `3e-15` it returns `1,856e+20` **<sup>*</sup>**
 <sub><sup>* *Comma is decimal separator in my locale*</sup></sub> 
What's up with this?

[image: Google screenshot. Search query: "3 fm in m". Result: "Length: 3 Femtometre = 1,856e+20 Meter." Formula: "for an approximate result, multiply the length value by 6,188e+19"]

Comment: Does this still happen? When I try, I don't get fm as an option to manually put it in the converter and searching doesn't auto-populate it either.

Comment: @Laurel it's entered in the search box. Depending on your locale you may find `to` triggers the unit conversion better than `in`. Femtometers are not part of the default length unit list and are added once triggered from a unit conversion-based search.

Answer (score 0):

## Appears to be a Bug

### Observations

1. Femtometre is not listed by default in Google's 'unit conversion' length list but is added as a result of the actual search.
2. Note the spelling variation between femtomet**re**  and met**er** which is peculiar as I would expect both to follow the same localization rules.
3. When I trigger the alternative "femtomet**er**" spelling in 'unit conversion' (in my locale), the conversion becomes accurate.
4. I can only trigger the alternative spelling (accurate unit conversion) in the following way:

   1. Using the full unit name "femtometer" (either spelling) without specifying any quantity. For example, all of the following will work:

      ```
      m to femtometer        m to femtometre  
      meter to femtometer    meter to femtometre
      metre to femtometer    metre to femtometre
      femtometer to m        femtometre to m  
      femtometer to meter    femtometre to meter
      femtometer to metre    femtometre to metre
      ```
   2. Specifying a 'from' quantity as long as the unit conversion is to, not from, the full unit name femtometer(s), with either spelling:

      ```
      3 m to femtometer      3 m to femtometre  
      3 meter to femtometer  3 meter to femtometre
      3 metre to femtometer  3 metre to femtometre
      ```
   3. Specifying a 'to' quantity as long as the unit conversion is to, not from, the full unit name femtometre(s), and the **US spelling is not used**:

      ```
      m to 3 femtometre  
      meter to 3 femtometre
      metre to 3 femtometre
      ```

      [image: Google Search: "meter to 3 fentometre" Length: "3 Femtometer = 3e-15 Meter" Formula: "for an approximate result, divide the length value by 1e+15"]

### Reporting Incorrect Answers

At the bottom of the Google Search Help page, [Manage calculator, unit converter & color codes](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en),  under **Send feedback**, it indicates you should send feedback to Google if you get an incorrect answer.

> 1. At the top right of the page, click Settings [image: Settings][image: and then]**Send feedback**.
> 2. Enter your feedback.
> 3. Select **Send**

[image: settings button at the top right of the Google Search page]

[image: Send feedback form filled out with a description of the problem, a screenshot of the search results showing the , error and a checkbox selected that reads "We may email you for more information or updates"]

[image: Report sent, thank you! We use feedback like yours to help fix issues and improve Google services. Close button]

Comment: When I do the search [*meter to 3 femtometer*](https://www.google.com/search?q=meter+to+3+femtometer) (using my native—American—spelling), it says "for an approximate result, multiply the length value by 6.188e+19" and returns a result according to this incorrect formula ("1.856e+20"). For some reason, it's using the British spelling "femtometre" in the dropdown. The Chrome browser omnibox returns the correct answer without doing a search, however.